# VBA Change default pdf viewer

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

is it possible to change the default pdf viewer programmatically via vba to installed pdf adobe reader dc? Is there an example maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shell. You can specify the application path

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
    sPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.pdf"
    Shell sPath & " " & sFile
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Shell command to specify the executable which can be used for opening a file. But if you want to change the default application you need to deal with windows registry. The default application set in Windows registry, you will find Default apps in the registry location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`. The following sample code shows you how to create a file association by automating windows scripting host:

```
Sub AssociateFileTypeWithApp(EXT As String, FileType As String, _
FileName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim b As Object
Set b = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
With b
.regwrite "HKCR\" & EXT & "\", FileType
.regwrite "HKCR\" & FileType & "\", "MY file"
.regwrite "HKCR\" & FileType & "\DefaultIcon\", FileName
.regwrite "HKCR\" & FileType & "\shell\open\command\", FileName & " %L"
.regdelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & EXT & "\Application"
.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & EXT & "\Application", FileName
.regdelete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & EXT & "\OpenWithList\"
.regwrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & EXT & "\OpenWithList\a", FileName
End With
End Sub
```